# How to make SQL*Net connect string from tnsnames.ora entry?

Tags: oracle, connection-string, cognos, tnsnames

I am creating a data source on a reporting tool of IBM (Cognos). That asks SQL*Net connect string.

Following is my tnsnames.ora entry. I am able to connect with SQLPLUS and TNSPING from the client.

`OVDB =
  (DESCRIPTION =
    (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = 172.22.1.180)(PORT = 1521))
    (CONNECT_DATA =
      (SERVER = DEDICATED)
      (SERVICE_NAME = OVDB)
    )
  )`

What would be my SQL *Net connect string? Is it OVDB?

Cognos wants to connect with Oracle database through it (OCI).

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it's the name (or alias, or whatever) of the entry in your TNSNames file.

[IBM support documentation 'Where do I find the SQL*Net connect string to connect to an Oracle Database?'](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21344794)

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
(DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP) (HOST=172.22.1.180) (PORT=1521)) (CONNECT_DATA=(SERVER=DEDICATED) (SERVICE_NAME=OVDB)))
```